# View places in different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout

I must design an activity which has lots of imageview and text view. But when I tried to run it in different screen size, whole views change their places. For example a textview in 8.9" screen looks like:

http://oi61.tinypic.com/312citx.jpg

But when I try it in 4.7" screen it looks like

http://oi58.tinypic.com/2dc5x85.jpg

How can I handle this problem ?

Note: The other images seen on the pictures are belong to my background image. I only added textview for now

Answer (score 0):

Refer this documentation and design your layout accordingly.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html